# Gaussian Weighting for point re-distribution

Tags: opencv, probability, gaussian, normal-distribution

I am working with some points which are very compact together and therefore forming clusters amongst them is proving very difficult. Since I am new to this concept, I read in a paper about the concept of Gaussian weighting the points randomly or rather resampling using gaussian weight.

My question here is how are gaussian weight applied to the data points? Is it the actual normal distribution where I have to compute the means and the variance and SD and than randomly sample or there is other ways to do it. I am confused on this concept?

Can I get some hints on the concept please

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at book: 
[http://www.amazon.com/Pattern-Recognition-Learning-Information-Statistics/dp/0387310738](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387310738)
There is a good chapters on modeling point distributions.

Comment: thanks for the information. I got the book off the library but I could not locate the chapter. Could you please tell the chapter if you remember. Thank you

Comment: I think you should look at pages 24-28  (1.2.4 The Gaussian distribution) and also (2.3. The Gaussian Distribution) page 78.